# Slow database restore from SQL file, considering binary replication to rollback tests database

Tags: postgresql, cucumber, rollback, capybara, database-restore

When using Cucumber with Capybara, I have to load test database data from SQL data dump.
Unfortunately it takes 10s for each scenario, which slows down the tests.

I have found something like: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial#How_to_Replicate

Do you think binary replication will be quicker then using SQL files?

Is there anything I can do to make the restore quicker (I restore just data, not structure)?

What approaches would you recommend to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to put your test data into a "template" database (e.g. mydb_template)

To prepare the test scenario, you simply drop your database using `DROP DATABASE mydb` and recreate based on the template: `CREATE DATABASE mydb TEMPLATE = mydb_template;`.

Of course you'll need to connect to e.g. *template0* or the *postgres* database in order to be able to drop *mydb*.

I think this could be faster than importing a dump.

I recall a discussion on the PG mailing list regarding this approach and some performance problems with large "templates" that were fixed with 9.0.

Comment: Yeah, performance of createdb from a template was greatly sped up in 9.0 by doing all the fsyncing at the end of the operation.  Create database went from taking 10 or 15 seconds to a couple of seconds (assuming the template db wasn't huge).

Answer (score 0):

> (I restore just data, not structure)

[`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-copy.html) is always fastest for importing just data. Other answer deals with restoring a whole database.